# Wireguard aside IPSec site to site

Tags: ssh, ipsec, wireguard

I have the following scenario: Connecting to a server (A) through another server (B). My connection to B is via ssh normally. The connection between B and A is through ssh, but via VPN with Wireguard.

My problem is that now, the location where server A is, needs to create a VPN site to site. They will use IPSec.

My question is: Just I need to configure the B server with IpSec to be able to access A. Correct? Can wireguard and IPsec work side by side?